# parse_mode with MarkdownV2 for Telegram Bot displaying using PHP

Tags: php, markdown, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following PHP code with the parse_mode=MarkdownV2 and it isn't posting to the channel I have it linked to. I verified this works, because if I remove the parse_mode it will post to the channel. Do I have some type of formatting error before sending this to the telegram bot?

```
$realurl = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$encoded = urlencode($realurl ." \n**". $obj->region .' - '. $obj->org .'** - '. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .' Referrer: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );

file_get_contents($api_path."/sendmessage?chat_id=-152445&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$encoded");
```

Comment: What response is the API giving you, is there an error message in there?

Answer (score 0):

The [Telegram MarkdownV2 Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style) shows the following example for **bold** text:

> ```
> *bold \*text*
> ```

---

Your code shows:

```
$realurl ." \n**". $obj->region .' - '. $obj->org .'** - ' .
```

So you open and close the bold tag right away, therefore nothing is shown in bold.

---

###### You need to use a single `*` instead off the double `**`!

Answer (score 0):

Reason why it doesn't work is because you need to escape the following characters: . - _

```
Using \. \- \_
```

This is the error message you get if you submit a message with . in it:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse entities: 
Character '.' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\\'"}
```